# Why $H^1(0,1) = L^2(0,1)$ is not good?

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

From the theory of Hilbert bases and separability considerations one can easily derive a Hilbert space isomorphism between $H^1(0,1)$ and $L^2(0,1)$. I am convinced that such an isomorphism is useless: I know explicit examples of $L^2(0,1)$ functions whose distributional derivative is not $L^2(0,1)$ so in pratice (*e.g.* when inspecting the regularity of a solution of a PDE) I do not wish to identify these two spaces. So my question is:

Why don't I like this isomorphism? What should a "good" isomorphism satisfy?

Comment: Yes, for your purposes isomorphisms are useless. They tell you about structure and/or dimension of the space not a about properties of specific elements. I think that what you are looking for is embeddings.

Comment: This is a good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find isomorphism $A: H^1 \leftrightarrow L^2$ preserves addition, multiplication by scalar and inner product (and so norm, topology, convergence, etc.). But there is a lot of additional structures on both $H^1$ and $L^2$ that are not preserved. One example you already gave: you have a differentiation operator $D: H^1 \to L^2$, which is easy to define, but operator $X = DA^{-1}$ that corresponds to it will be very strange.